# How to efficiently update the column names in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to refactor the following code:

```
labels = list(df.columns)
labels[0] = labels[0].replace(' ', '_')
labels[1] = labels[1].replace(' ', '_')
labels[2] = labels[2].replace(' ', '_')
labels[3] = labels[3].replace(' ', '_')
labels[5] = labels[5].replace(' ', '_')
labels[6] = labels[6].replace(' ', '_')
df.columns = labels

df.head()
```

However I keep getting a ValueError when I run the code in Jupyter. I want to create integer indexes. This is what I refactored the code into:

```
labels = list(df.columns)
for label in labels: 
    label = int(label)
    labels[label] = labels[label].replace(' ', '_')
df.columns = labels

df.head()
```

How do I fix this? Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve with the dataframe(df) being renamed to remove spaces:

```
new_df = df.rename(columns={'fixed acidity': 'fixed_acidity',
                             'volatile acidity': 'volatile_acidity',
                             'citric acid': 'citric_acid',
                             'residual sugar': 'residual_sugar',
                             'free sulfur dioxide': 'free_sulfur_dioxide',
                             'total sulfur dioxide': 'total_sulfur_dioxide'
                            })
new_df.head()
```

Comment: Use [`enumerate(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate): `for i, label in enumerate(labels):`.

Comment: Do i use ```i``` or ```label```?

Comment: You use both: `labels[i] = label.replace(...)`.

Comment: Why not just `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(" ", "_")`?

Answer (score 1):

## Ways to fix the column names

- For making the same change to all column name

### Use a `list comprehension`

```py
df.columns = [col.replce(' ', '_') for col in df.columns]
```

### Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas-series-str-replace)

- As mentioned in the comments by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7093741/chris)
- **This is the best option**

```py
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(" ", "_")
```

### Use a `for-loop`

- It is not necessary to do `list(df.columns)`
- It is not necessary to use `enumerate`

```py
labels = list()

for col in df.columns:
    labels.append(col.replace(' ', '_'))

df.columns = labels
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
labels = list(df.columns)
for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    labels[i] = label.replace(' ', '_')

df.columns = labels

df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use listcomprehension instead of for.

`labels = list(df.columns)
labels = [label.replace(' ', '_') for label in labels]
df.columns = labels`

The error in your code is :

`for label in labels:` instead of 'for label in range(len(labels)):`